# How do I make a j-query photo gallery slider play nice with duplicate slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

First off, I am very new to j-query. That being said, I have a very simple j-query photo gallery slider that holds images and fades into new ones every few seconds. I have a page where I duplicated it, and gave it different css and class/id names in the js to make a different one. I want both on the same page. Now that I have the second one up and running perfectly. It's causing the first one to not work even though they share different css,html, and j-query script

Here is the all the code for the first one:

j-query:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function theRotator() {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('div#rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
    $('div#rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval('rotate()',10000);

}

function rotate() { 
    //Get the first image
    var current = ($('div#rotator ul li.show')?  $('div#rotator ul li.show') : $('div#rotator ul li:first'));

    //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div#rotator ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div#rotator ul li:first'));   

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('show')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
    .removeClass('show');

};

$(document).ready(function() {      
    //Load the slideshow
    theRotator();
});

</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="new_home_photo" class="round_10px">
    <div id="rotator">
        <ul>
            <li class="show">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div id="photo_1" class="round_7px">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div id="photo_2" class="round_7px">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div id="photo_3" class="round_7px">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
/* rotator in-page placement */
div#rotator {position:relative;height:345px;margin-left:0px;}

/* rotator css */
div#rotator ul li {float:left;position:absolute;list-style:none;}

/* rotator image style */   
div#rotator ul li img {vertical-align:left;}

div#rotator ul li.show {z-index:500;}

#photo_1 {background:url(images/home_actual_1.jpg)no-repeat; width:621px;height:420px;}

#photo_2 {background:url(images/home_actual_2.jpg)no-repeat; width:621px;height:420px;}

#photo_3 {background:url(images/home_actual_3.jpg)no-repeat; width:621px;height:420px;}
```

Here is the second one the is working and caused this first one to stop working:

j-query:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function theRotator() {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('div#rotator_update ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
    $('div#rotator_update ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval('rotate()',10000);

}

function rotate() { 
    //Get the first image
    var current = ($('div#rotator_update ul li.show_update')?  $('div#rotator_update ul li.show_update') : $('div#rotator_update ul li:first'));

    //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show_update')) ? $('div#rotator_update ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div#rotator_update ul li:first'));  

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('show_update')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
    .removeClass('show_update');

};

$(document).ready(function() {      
    //Load the slideshow
    theRotator();
});

</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="new_home_update">
    <div id="rotator_update">
        <ul>
            <li class="show_update">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div id="update_1" class="round_7px">
                <a href="http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/ptc-therapeutics-awarded-16-million-fda-orphan-drug-grant-to-support-an-ongoing-phase-3-study-in-cystic-fibrosis-103425769.html" target="_blank">
                PTC Therapeutics Awarded $1.6 Mil FDA Orphan Drug Grant to Support an Phase 3 Study in CF
                </a>
                </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div id="update_2" class="round_7px">
                <a href="http://www.docguide.com/news/content.nsf/news/852576140048867C852577A4005BDB10" target="_blank">
                Denufosol Provides Significant Lung Function Improvement in Patients With Mild Cystic Fibrosis
                </a>
                </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div id="update_3" class="round_7px">
                <a href="http://www.news-medical.net/news/20100918/Researchers-identify-new-target-for-cystic-fibrosis.aspx" target="_blank">
                Researchers identify new target for cystic fibrosis
                <a/>
                </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div#rotator_update {position:relative;height:345px;margin-left:0px;}

/* rotator css */
div#rotator_update ul li {float:left;position:absolute;list-style:none;}

/* rotator image style */   
div#rotator_update ul li img {vertical-align:left;}

div#rotator_update ul li.show_update {z-index:500;}

#update_1 { width:621px;height:420px;margin:7px auto 7px 60px;}

#update_1 a {text-decoration:none; font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#999999;text-align:center;}

#update_1 a:hover {color:#F16C22;}

#update_2 { width:621px;height:420px;margin:7px auto 7px 60px;}

#update_2 a {text-decoration:none; font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#999999;text-align:center;}

#update_2 a:hover {color:#F16C22;}

#update_3 { width:621px;height:420px;margin:7px auto 7px 60px;}

#update_3 a {text-decoration:none; font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#999999;text-align:center;}

#update_3 a:hover {color:#F16C22;}
```

I have also tried many combinations of renaming classes and sharing classes and nothing has caused them to work at the same time.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your functions are still named the same (i.e. `theRotator` and `rotate` appear twice in the page), which is causing the issue.

The best solution would be to change your `theRotator` and `rotate` methods so that you can pass in the ID of whichever slideshow you want to rotate. Something like:

```
function theRotator(sliderId) {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('div#' + sliderId + 'ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
    $('div#' + sliderId + ' ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval('rotate(' + sliderId + ')',10000);
}

function rotate(sliderId) { 
    //Get the first image
    var current = ($('div#' + sliderId + 'ul li.show')?  $('div#' + sliderId + ' ul li.show') : $('div#' + sliderId + ' ul li:first'));

    ...
};

$(document).ready(function() {      
    //Load the slideshows
    theRotator('rotator');
    theRotator('rotator_update');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! that totally worked. I was on the right path but did not try changing the rotate(). Have a good one.